# Complete a data.frame with new values by group

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

The `tidyr` package has the very useful `complete` function, which allows us to make "missing" rows explicit: you pass all the relevant columns to the function and it makes sure all possible combinations exist, creating new rows if needed with the missing combinations. You can also give it the expected values of a given column (i.e. `calendar_quarter = 1:4`).

There's also `nesting()`, which can be used within `complete()` to group columns so that only the existing combinations of those columns are used.

However, what about an "intermediate" case? That is, one where we want to give different expected values for each group? This is best shown with an example:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~year, ~semester,
  1, 2000, 1,
  1, 2001, 1,
  1, 2001, 2,
  
  2, 1999, 1,
  2, 1999, 2,
  2, 2001, 1
)
```

Here we have a table with years and semesters where a given `id` was relevant. However, we are missing some semesters (2000S1 for `id=1` and 2000S1, 2000S2 and 2001S2 for `id=2`).

First we try using `nesting()`, since we'll otherwise create rows for `id=1, year=1999`, which we don't need:

```r
complete(df, nesting(id, year), semester = 1:2)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>      id  year semester
#>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1  2000        1
#> 2     1  2000        2  # new
#> 3     1  2001        1
#> 4     1  2001        2
#> 5     2  1999        1
#> 6     2  1999        2
#> 7     2  2001        1
#> 8     2  2001        2  # new
```

This is ok, filling out some missing semesters for both `id`s. However, it still hides the missing year 2000 for `id=2`. This is natural, since we didn't tell `complete()` to use any extra values for the `year` column.

So let's do that. We have to ditch `nesting()`, and then we can tell `complete()` to check for the existence of the entire range of known years:

```r
complete(df, id, year = min(year):max(year), semester = 1:2)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>       id  year semester
#>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1  1999        1  # new, unwanted
#>  2     1  1999        2  # new, unwanted
#>  3     1  2000        1
#>  4     1  2000        2  # new
#>  5     1  2001        1
#>  6     1  2001        2
#>  7     2  1999        1
#>  8     2  1999        2
#>  9     2  2000        1  # new
#> 10     2  2000        2  # new
#> 11     2  2001        1
#> 12     2  2001        2  # new
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is better, showing all the missing semesters, including the year 2000 for `id=2`.

However, it came at the cost of also exposing the year 1999 for `id=1`, which we don't want.

**So, is there an elegant way of getting the following output?**

```r
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       id  year semester
#>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1  2000        1
#>  2     1  2000        2  # new
#>  3     1  2001        1
#>  4     1  2001        2
#>  5     2  1999        1
#>  6     2  1999        2
#>  7     2  2000        1  # new
#>  8     2  2000        2  # new
#>  9     2  2001        1
#> 10     2  2001        2  # new
```

The only solution I've come up with would be to build another table `startEndY` to store the initial and final years for each `id`, run `complete(df, id, year = min(year):max(year), semester = 1:2)` and then perform a join between `df` and `startEndY` to trim out the unwanted results, but that seems inelegant and slow, since the `complete()` will create many unnecessary rows (especially in my actual use-case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `complete` the missing observations per `id` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% tidyr::complete(year = min(year):max(year), semester)

#      id  year semester
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1  2000        1
# 2     1  2000        2
# 3     1  2001        1
# 4     1  2001        2
# 5     2  1999        1
# 6     2  1999        2
# 7     2  2000        1
# 8     2  2000        2
# 9     2  2001        1
#10     2  2001        2
```

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware that `complete` respected `group_by`!